# Is sending verification code via call considered a VOIP functionality?

Tags: ios, voip, pushkit

If I implement a callout verification code in an iOS app, does it means I'm implementing a VOIP functionality? And does that mean I could use PushKit in the app (so that the app could wake up after killed by the user when a push notification comes in), without the app being rejected from App Store?

Comment: Are you calling a VoIP endpoint inside your app or is some server just calling the user's mobile phone number?  The former is VoIP functionality, the latter isn't

Comment: @Paulw11, thanks! Tt should be the server calling the user's mobile phone, since it will be the server generating code..

Comment: Then your app won’t be a voip app